# 1 Year Service on Steam, but no badge earned

Tags: steam, achievements

It says my steam account is 1-year-old today, but the badge for the years of service isn't showing up. Is it delayed a day or something?

Link to my profile: http://steamcommunity.com/id/Undelt

Comment: 65 badges and only a year old? Wow I need to step my badge game up!

Answer (score 3):

Read this post from the Steam Forums, very similar issue. It appears that it is directly related to the time of your first purchase/activation of a game.

It took the OP nearly an hour before it showed up. The other thing I'd say is make sure you are active on your account.

http://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/528398719809378390/